# How To show Database value in messagebox

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Iam new in vb script iam trying to retrieve value from table and shown to front end base on entering employee code respective employee name should shown for that i written code in vb script but it wont run giving error,i unable to find where is issue

Line:3
Char:18
Error: expected end of statement
Code:800A0401
Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error

```
Private Sub CheckOriginalData()
        Dim employee_code 
        Dim dtAB As DataTable
        dim a
        Using cn As New SqlConnection( "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=testing;Initial Catalog=adventure;user id ='UAT_01';password='Basket@123'")
            Dim cmdAB As String = "select employee_name from employee_details where leadid= @employee_code;"
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdAB, cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@employee_code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employee_code.Text
                cn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    dtAB.Load(dr)
                    a = InputBox("Enter a Number" &employee_code.Text)
         msgbox a
                         MsgBox("your lead id is: " & employee_code.Text & " and status is ", cmdAB & "")
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        If (dtAB.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            employee_code.Focus()
        Else          
          
           MsgBox("Leads not found")
            employee_code.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't believe your userid/pw should be quoted in your connection string.

Comment: Should `msgbox a` should be off by itself like that?

Comment: Your code is not valid vbscript. It might be VB or VB.net, I'm not sure. Line the third line is wrong already as vbscript is not typed. `As DataTable` is invalid.

Comment: @GeertBellekens it’s VB.Net as VB does not support `using` or ADO.Net objects and syntax.

Comment: vbscript is not vb.net - question body disagrees with tags. Please align. You appear to be using some valid vb.net in a vbscript environment, which won't work any more than pasting Java in would. Either switch to using vb.net environment (visual studio is free and better, and you'd be learning a programming language someone would probably want to employ you for) or follow a vb script tutorial not a vb.net one

Comment: Just specify a type; dim a As String

Comment: The very first thing you need to do it put Option Strict On in Project Properties.

Answer (score 0):

By this line

```
Dim employee_code
```

You have declared a local variable of type `Object`. Then you try to assign the `Text` property of an object to the `Value` of a `Parameter`. An `Object` doesn't have a `Text` property. I assume that you have a `TextBox` on your form named `employee_code`.

I am wondering about your connection string including `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;` I haven't seen that before in my SQL Server connections but I lead a sheltered life and it might be fine. The provider is provider by the ADO.net code. It does appear in Access connection strings.

You don't have any code that returns a `DataTable`. To call `Load` on a `DataTable` you need an instance of the class. This is accomplished by using the `New` keyword which calls the constructor of `DataTable`. But we end up not using a `DataTable`.

You can add the command to the same `Using` block with a comma at the end of the first line of the `Using`.

I don't see the purpose of these lines. You have already assigned a value to the parameter.

```
a = InputBox("Enter a Number" & employee_code.Text)
 MsgBox a
```

Don't show message boxes while a connection is open. The user could have gone to lunch and no one is there to click OK. Your connection is left flapping in the breeze.

Since you are only retrieving a single piece of data, the employee name, you can use `.ExecuteScalar` method of the command. The returns the first column of the first row in the result set. You need to add `.ToString` because `ExecuteScalar` returns an `Object`.

For some unknow reason you are displaying your select string, `cmdAB`, in a message box.

```
MsgBox("your lead id is: " & employee_code.Text & " and status is ", cmdAB & "")
```

You also appear to be missing an ampersand and have double quotes at the end. You have not retrieved any information on status so this data would not be available to display. This is a good reason to use an interpolated string denoted by the leading `$`. You can then insert variable surrounded by `{ }` braces directly in line where you want them to appear.

Finally, I separated your user interface code from your database code. This way your function can be used by any front end.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Private Function GetEmployeeName(EmployeeCode As String) As String
    Dim EmployeeName As String
    Dim cmdAB As String = "select employee_name from employee_details where leadid= @employee_code;"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=testing;Initial Catalog=adventure;user id ='UAT_01';password='Basket@123'"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdAB, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@employee_code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmployeeCode
        cn.Open()
        EmployeeName = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString
    End Using
    Return EmployeeName
End Function

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim EmployeeName = GetEmployeeName(employee_code.Text)
    MessageBox.Show($"your lead id is: {employee_code.Text} and Name is {EmployeeName}")
End Sub
```